# C# Dynamic Class Type -- generate lambda expression for DbContext .Select

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

So I have to generate dynamic classes at runtime.  I use AssemblyBuilder, ModuleBuilder, TypeBuilder.  I can get the Type and created an instance with Activator.

But later I need to use the type as part of a derived DbContext.  I got that far.

But now I need to generate a .Select expression in the DbContext for specifying just the columns I want to select.  I found a method to do this.

```
public static Func<T, T> DynamicSelectGenerator<T>(string fields = "")
{
   ...

   return lambda.Compile();
}
```

But I can't figure out how to send my dynamic class's Type into this method.

How do I turn my type into a generic type to pass into this DynamicSelectGenerator ?

I've tried to take my type and call type.MakeGenericType(), but that isn't working.

How would I use this Type of a dynamic class built at runtime to generate my Select clause lambda expression?

I've tried using Dynamic Linq but am getting errors with that approach as well.

Comment: That sounds like a lot of work, but you haven't explained why you are doing all this (eg an XY Problem). Note that you need `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod` to invoke a generic method via reflection. And you'll want an `Expression<Func<T, T>>` to call `IQueryable<T>.Select`.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Jeremy.  I'll give it a shot.  It's because this API has to be able to connect to some databases with potentially unknown tables and structures in them.  So I'm actually creating an entity at runtime and a dynamic DbContext so that I can then query the tables using Dynamic Linq. It's definitely been a project.  I'll try your approach.

Comment: If everything is dynamic, then EF Core feels like the wrong solution.

Comment: It's actually been working amazingly well for me.  I ran into this issue because I was getting error from Dynamic Linq.  I was finally able to get past that by simply moving the .Select part of the query in front of the Skip. and Take.  For some reason that was causing the error and my problem is now solved.  I do have to learn more about Generics and Types.  Thank you for your help.